# fgets "Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC." error

Tags: c, fgets

```
Error: Unhandled exception at 0x60092A8D (msvcr110d.dll) in C_Son60.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

When below code executed this error code is given.(Compiles successfully)
Where is my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;

int main(void){

char *names[3];

//get the names of the cities
puts("Enter names of cities");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    fgets( names[i], 99, stdin);
}
//print entered names
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("%s", *names[i]);
}

getch();
}
```

Comment: you need to allocate memory in the name char pointer array.

Comment: 0xCCCCCCCC is what MS stores in unallocated memory ... in this case, `names[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

1. you need to allocate the strings you created- you can do it with `malloc(100 * sizeof(char))`
2. when printing you do `*names[i]` which means - `**(names + i)`.

all you need is `names[i]`

use the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;

int main(void){
    char *names[3];

    //get the names of the cities
    puts("Enter names of cities");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        names[i] = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        fgets( names[i], 99, stdin);
    }
    //print entered names
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", names[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate memory to which the char pointers point to before you read them in

for instance:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  names[i] = malloc(200);
  fgets( names[i], 99, stdin);
}
```

Comment: 3 IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *" This error is given when I did it

Comment: use `names[i] = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));` like i show in my answer @user1939432

Comment: if you're using standard C then it will compile, you are using a C++ compiler apparently where the cast is necessary

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen it is always better to cast, and to allocate memory based on the size needed.

Comment: I dont agree with the "always better to cast" argument. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate your memory before storing anything into it. When you need to allocate an array of elements, and you do not know the number of elements at compile time, you must use [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) to allocate them.

Don't forget to [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) your dynamically allocated memory later in order to avoid memory leaks!

Comment: If I knew that each city name would be maximum 50 characters long, can I do it without using malloc?

Comment: Then you could make it an array of lenght [50]